# Why i cant align my cardview to the top of the screen? (XML)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I got a cardview layout which is loaded in a placeholderview. so far so good, but the cardview wont align to the top when there is no margin/padding/align or whatever. i guess i dont see my xml error. i appreciate your help!

Here is a picture of my screen: [image: myscreen]

Here is my code of the cardview:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:layout_widthPercent="94%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="70%"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                android:layout_weight="0.02"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="type"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="35%"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:border_width="3dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="70%"
                android:text="jobkind"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="90%"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="company"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="80%">



                <ImageView
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                    android:src="@drawable/place_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/durTxt"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                    android:text="duration"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="11dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <ImageView
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="68%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                    android:src="@drawable/euro" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placeTxt"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
                    android:text="place"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="11dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/salTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
                android:text="salary"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="68%"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Here is a preview pic: [image: cardview preview]

And here is the placeholderview where is load in my cardview

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >

    <com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView
        android:id="@+id/swipeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/rejectBtn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cancel" />
            <!--android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel"-->


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/acceptBtn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/check"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">
        </LinearLayout>



    </com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

A preview pic of the placeholderview

[image: placeholder]

I thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: why does your root view have a weight of 5?

Comment: try applying `android:layout_gravity="top"` for the `cardView`..

Comment: that was for testing but it doesnt change something, because in this area isnt anything. But thanks for noticing :)

Comment: i tried that but sadly it wont help. i appreciate your help :)!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your cardview with this :

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:layout_widthPercent="94%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="70%"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeTxt"
            app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="type"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="35%"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:border_width="3dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descTxt"
            app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="70%"
            android:text="jobkind"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comTxt"
            app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="90%"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="company"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />


        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="80%">



            <ImageView
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                android:src="@drawable/place_icon" />

            <ImageView
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/clock_icon" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/durTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                android:text="duration"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="68%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                android:src="@drawable/euro" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeTxt"
                app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
                android:text="place"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/salTxt"
            app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
            android:text="salary"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="68%"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what did you change and why?

Comment: just changed some width and height based on my own cardview that is always stack on top of the view where is loaded and toggled off the weight.

Comment: cant use wrap_parent there. isnt it? ty!

Comment: is there some advice left :) i would appreciate it a hella lot!

Comment: Actually i'm using a recyclerview with my cardview so it's easy to positionate it on the center. Try to put an LinearLayout wrapping the area above the placeholder and then put in it your cardview.